# neo4j null pointer exception while saving via @Repository

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

> The sample project i'm working with can be found attached here -
>   [Spring Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-897)

This is my configuration

```
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.graph.repository")
public class DBConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration{
    @Value("${neo4j.location}")
    private String neo4jDatabaseLocation;

    @Override
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory(getConfiguration(), "com.graph.entity");
    }

    @Bean
    public Configuration getConfiguration() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.driverConfiguration()
            .setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver")
            .setURI(neo4jDatabaseLocation);
        return configuration;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public Session getSession() throws Exception {
        return getSessionFactory().openSession();
    }
}
```

Abstract Entity

```
public abstract class Entity {
@GraphId
private Long id;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || id == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Entity entity = (Entity) o;

    if (!id.equals(entity.id)) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (id == null) ? -1 : id.hashCode();
}
}
```

This is my Entity

```
@NodeEntity(label = "Patient")
public class Patient extends Entity {
private String patientId;
private String patientName;
private String otherPatientId;
private String sex;
private String dateOfBirth;
private String patientIdIssuer;
@Relationship(type = "STUDY", direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED)
private Set<Study> studies;

Getters and Setters...
}
```

Study has nested entity/relationship and that has another nested entity/relationship. 1:N relationship

This is my repository

```
@Repository
public interface PatientRepository extends GraphRepository<Patient> {
}
```

And this is the calling method

```
public class Test() {
    @Autowired
    private PatientRepository patientRepository;

    public void test() {
        Patient patient = new Patient();
        // set fields
        patientRepository.save(patient); -> This is where I get NPE
    }
}
```

Stack Trace :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver.nativeTransaction(EmbeddedDriver.java:180) ~[neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver-2.0.4.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver.newTransaction(EmbeddedDriver.java:148) ~[neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver-2.0.4.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.transaction.DefaultTransactionManager.openTransaction(DefaultTransactionManager.java:57) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.4.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.TransactionsDelegate.beginTransaction(TransactionsDelegate.java:37) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.4.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.beginTransaction(Neo4jSession.java:441) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.4.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.request.RequestExecutor.executeSave(RequestExecutor.java:84) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.4.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:75) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.4.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:44) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.4.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.save(Neo4jSession.java:425) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.4.jar:na]
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong??

Note : I had this working earlier with sdn.3.x with GraphDatabaseService

Comment: Are you sure the graph database location is read? Can you verify that the graphDatabaseService is set up in getSessionFactory() by checking if null with  EmbeddedDriver embeddedDriver = (EmbeddedDriver) Components.driver();
                GraphDatabaseService databaseService = embeddedDriver.getGraphDatabaseService();

Comment: embeddedDriver and databaseService both are not null. Checked just before making the .save() call

Comment: Can you share your Entity class?

Comment: updated in the question

Comment: Which version of sdn?

Comment: <spring-data-neo4j.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</spring-data-neo4j.version>

Comment: @Luanne: Found anything???

Comment: Not yet, can't see anything obvious. If you can turn this into a test case and log it at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH/, that would help

Comment: Here is the issue - https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-897. Attached the sample project with it

Comment: Please try out the answer and let me know. Works for me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the only thing missing is the `@Configuration` annotation on your `Neo4jConfiguration` class:

```
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.seyfert.matrix.graph.repository")
public class DBConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration{
...
```